# How can I automatically update a view using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a cache and a cron-job for pulling/receiving and saving data. I want that the view updates itself. For testing it should update every 5 seconds. In this way I should see, when the data is pulled, saved to cache and finally will appear on the view.

I found out that socket.io can help me. I haven't found a suited example to my purpose. Can somebody help me?

Here is a snippet of my code from app.js:

```
 var dashboardData = "";

 //----fired when cache has changed
 myCache.on( "set", function( key, value ){
     stats = JSON.stringify(myCache.getStats());
     stats = JSON.parse(stats);
     console.log(stats.keys);
     var content = JSON.stringify(value);
     content = JSON.parse(content);
     dashboardData = content;
 });

 //----load dashboard view
 app.post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
     projectName = req.body.selectProjectName;
     if(dashboardData == ""){
         var content = "";
         dashboard.dashboard(req,res, projectName, content); 
      } else {
         dashboard.dashboard(req,res, projectName, dashboardData.variable); 
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution: I've added a jquery javascript with an asynchronous ajax call that updates the view every 5 seconds.